# Arranging graphviz clusters

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to generate the following construct:
I have four graphs. Three of them are supposed to be in the first "row", all vertically aligned by their vertical center. The fourth graph is supposed to be below the other three, in the second "row". It should be horizontally aligned with either the horizontal center of the upper row's middle graph or the horizontal center of the entire upper row. Additionally there will be edges between some members of separate clusters/graphs.
[image: Here is an example.] Here there are only edges between members of cluster_a and cluster_d, but there may be edges between members of any combination of clusters.

Comment: Please show what you got sofar (as code in the question).

Answer (score 0):

Ususal you can do this by adding some additional invisible scarfolding nodes and edges e.g.:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR
    edge[minlen=2]//enable finer control over node location when scarfolding
    subgraph cluster_d { label=cluster_d
        d_0->d_2
        d_1->d_0
        //d_1->d_3
        //extra node to simulate edge between edges
        d_13[shape=point]
        d_1->d_13[dir=none minlen=1]
        d_13->d_3[minlen=1]
        d_3->d_2
        d_3->d_3
    }
    subgraph cluster_abc { // better align cluster
    subgraph cluster_a { label=cluster_a
        a_0->a_2
        a_0->a_3
        a_1->a_0
        a_1->a_1 
        a_1->a_2
        a_1->a_3
        //a_2->a_3
        //extra node to simulate edge between edges
        a_23[shape=point]
        a_2->a_23[dir=none minlen=1]
        a_23->a_3[minlen=1]
        a_3->a_2
        a_3->a_3
    }
    subgraph cluster_c { label=cluster_c
        c_0->c_0
        c_0->c_1
        c_0->c_2
        c_0->c_3
        c_1->c_3
        c_3->c_3
        c_2->c_0
        c_2->c_1
        c_2->c_2
        c_2->c_3
    }
    subgraph cluster_b { label=cluster_b
        b_0->b_0
        b_0->b_2
        b_0->b_3
        b_1->b_1
        b_1->b_2
        b_1->b_3
        b_2->b_0
        b_3->b_2
    }
    color=invis
    }
    {//scarfolding
        edge[style=invis]node[style=invis] //hide scarfolding
        {
            rank=same 
            node[shape=point] //minimize impact on edge routing around the scarfolding nodes
            x_0 
            x_1
        }
        a_3->c_0
        c_3->b_0
        // we can not use same rank across cluster boundary so instead of a_3->d_1 we do a_2->x_0 + x_1->d_1
        a_2->x_0 
        x_1->d_1[minlen=3]
    }
    {
        edge[headclip=false tailclip=false]
        a_2->d_1[dir=none constraint=false]
        a_3->d_3[dir=none]
    }
    a_23->d_13[dir=none constraint=false]
}
```

[image: rendered on viz-js.com]